# Interface expected here (Main Activity)

Tags: java, android, generics, interface, retrofit

I am using retrofit and I need to do CommonCallback for AuthResponse to reuse it again and again .. in my application.

**CommonCallBack.java:**

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public abstract class CommonCallBack<RES> implements Callback<RES> {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<RES> call, Response<RES> response) {
        onResSucceeded(call, response);
    }

    protected abstract void onResSucceeded(Call<RES> call, Response<RES> response);

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<RES> call, Throwable t) {
        onResFailure(call, t);
    }

    protected abstract void onResFailure(Call<RES> call, Throwable t);


}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CommonCallBack<AuthResponse> {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ..........
        call.enqueue(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResSucceeded(Call<AuthResponse> call, Response<AuthResponse> response) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResFailure(Call<AuthResponse> call, Throwable t) {

    }
```

> Error on implements CommonCallBack : Interface expected here

Comment: Well yes, `CommonCallBack` is a class, not an interface. You can't "implement" a class.

Answer (score 0):

With java 8 you can make your `CommonCallBack`-class an interface and use `default` methods for the delegation call:

```
public interface CommonCallBack<RES> implements Callback<RES> {

    @Override
    default void onResponse(Call<RES> call, Response<RES> response) {
        onResSucceeded(call, response);
    }

    void onResSucceeded(Call<RES> call, Response<RES> response);

    @Override
    default void onFailure(Call<RES> call, Throwable t) {
        onResFailure(call, t);
    }

    void onResFailure(Call<RES> call, Throwable t);
}
```

That way your `MainActivity`-class can implement `CommonCallBack`